# Quadratic Formula Failing when A > 1?

Tags: java, android, quadratic

I am in the process of developing my first app which solves the quadratic formula and I have run into a problem that the app gives the wrong answers for the roots when the value fo a is greater than 1.
This is the code:

```
package com.example.firstapp;
import java.lang.Math;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void calculate(View v){
        EditText number1text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.a);
        EditText number2text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.b);
        EditText number3text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.c);
        double num1 = Double.parseDouble(number1text.getText().toString()) , num2 = Double.parseDouble(number2text.getText().toString()), num3 = Double.parseDouble(number3text.getText().toString());
        if ((num2 * num2) - (4*num1*num3) < 0){

        }

        double ans = (double) ((-(num2)- (Math.sqrt(num2 * num2 - (4*num1*num3))))/2*num1);

        double ans2 = (double) (((-(num2)+ Math.sqrt(num2 * num2 - (4*num1*num3))))/2*num1);


        TextView answer = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ans1);
        answer.setText("The first root is: " + ans);
        TextView answer2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ans2);
        answer2.setText("The second root is: " + ans2);

    }


    private TextView getText(String string) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Any help as to why this is happening would be very useful.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Well for one thing, there is nothing inside your if statement.

Comment: When you check if b*b-4ac is less than zero you should have the code to calculate ans1 and ans2 inside an else. Otherwise if the determinant is less than zero it still calculates it. As well as that there is a lot of irrelevant code and num1, num2 and num3 aren't good names for variables consider changing them to a, b, c to match the standard way of writing the formula

Comment: There's nothing wrong with adding features one at a time until the program does everything it needs to do.  OP hasn't dealt with the "no roots case" yet, which is fine, because he/she has still not finished getting the "a != 1" case right.

Answer (score 1):

The correct formula is `-b ±  sqrt(b^2 - 4ac) / (2a)`

You have `-b ±  sqrt(b^2 - 4ac) / 2 * a`

Brackets would help i.e. around 2*num1